# Error "unknown URL type: urlopen error" in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, subprocess, text-mining

This is my code, I want to extract web's 'title' from an URL that user inputs, but it doesn't work.

```
    import re
    import urllib.request

    url = input('Please enter website URL : ')
    h = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    code = h.read()
    pattern = re.compile(r'<title>(.+)</title>', re.M)

    title = re.findall(pattern, code)
    print("%s title is : %s") % (url, title)
```

> the answer must be like this:

```
>>> url = raw_input('Please enter website URL : ') 
Please enter website URL : http://www.google.com/ 
>>> h = urllib.urlopen(url) >>> code = h.read() 
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'<title>(.+)</title>', re.M) 
>>> title = re.findall(pattern, code) 
>>> print("%s title is : %s") % (url, title) 
>>>output: http://www.google.com/ title is : ['Google']
```

Comment: whats the output Afasn?

Answer (score 2):

In the subject it says `htttp`, so it looks like you just typo'ed `http` by adding an extra `t` when you entered it to test.